# How to Stitch Date and Time into Time Stamps？

Tags: sql, database, time, dolphindb

In the DolphinDB table, how do I match the date with the time? When my date is greater than 10, there will be an error. What should I do?

```
fv =  table(2012.12.01 2012.12.12 2012.12.13 as date, 12:12:12.123 12:12:12.124  13:13:13.123 as time)
select temporalParse(date.format('y/M/d')+time.format('H:m:s.SSS'),'y/M/dH:m:s.SSS') from fv
```

From the above statement, I get the result that only 2012.12.01 12:12:12.123
how can i get the other result?

Answer (score 0):

First, your code has a minor bug. The date format 'y/M/d' doesn't have fixed length for day and month. For this reason, you must insert an delimiter between date and time. The code after correction looks like:

```
fv =  table(2012.12.01 2012.12.12 2012.12.13 as date, 12:12:12.123 12:12:12.124  13:13:13.123 as time)
select temporalParse(date.format('y/M/dT')+time.format('H:m:s.SSS'),'y/M/dTH:m:s.SSS') from fv
```

Second, string format, concatenation, and parse are inefficient. Please directly use temporal addition as follows.

```
select timestamp(date) + int(time) as dt from fv
```